# Geany / Gedit: hex editor plugin

Tags: gedit, binary, geany

Are there any plugins for Geany / Gedit to support reading binary/hex files?

Comment: There is a list of Gedit plugins [here](https://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins)  And Geeny Plugins [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/263793/geany-gedit-hex-editor-plugin)though none for editing binary files.  If it does not need to be a plugin then take a look at "Bless hex editor" and "GHex" both available in the software centre.

Comment: @WarrenHill Your second link should probably point to [here](http://plugins.geany.org/). :)

Comment: Both "Bless hex editor" and "GHex" are fantastic and similar. My preference slightly tilted to "Bless hex editor" for a little better UI feel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you would be better off using a dedicated software. I confess that I have not used it but [Bless](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bless) looks interesting, as mentioned by the comment above (just saw it now...).

Comment: Yes, Thanks. I have already tried this and it is good as I have already commented!

Answer (score 1):

I've written a script for the Geany Lua plugin that allows you to do hex editing.

The file is available from https://wiki.geany.org/config/scripts/lua

You just have to install the Geany Lua plugin (available via apt-get as geany-plugin-lua), copy the script into your config directory (~/.config/geany/plugins/geanylua), and restart Geany. The script will appear under Tools - Lua Scripts.

If you have the Bless hex editor, the script will open files in that. Otherwise, if you have xxd (which comes standard with vim), then it will allow you to edit the file as hex within Geany.

Feedback is welcome!

Comment: This works, and the Geany interface is perhaps a little warmer. Note that even with Bless installed, files still opened in Geany (which is fine for me).

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple trick in Geany I use for easy switching between Geany and GHex.

Activate the built-in file browser plugin in Geany and go to its preferences to configure it. Check the option *“Follow the path of the current file”* and set an external open command, e. g. `ghex -g 1024x768 "%f"`.

Now open any file with Geany. If you want work on the hex code simply go into the built-in file browser (it's always in the right path) and use right click on your file and select *“Open externally”*. Geany will open the file in GHex automatically. After you are done with GHex, close it. If you have something changed in the file you just have to reload the file in Geany. It's a simple efficient workflow.